# Why do i have duplicated menu on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu

Here i am creating 2 menu sites "Main" and "Central"

```
 if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
     register_nav_menus(
          array(
              'main' => 'Main',
              'central' => 'Central' 
         )
     );
  }
```

when i am creating menus on wordpress aperience, menus 
and i am puting them on their sites
PRS menu on Main
and central on Central

When i have incerted my menus on web

```
       <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main','menu_class' => 'menu' )); ?>
       <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Central','menu_class' => 'menu' )); ?>
```

But on my web i am seyng "central" menu 2 times and PRS dont apear.
What is the problem and what solution cn i find?

Comment: Your code looks perfect (I can't find any flaws). Makes me wonder if you might have just mixed up adding the menu to the correct "Theme location" setting in the "Menu Settings" in the admin. Can you verify both menu's have been linked to the correct menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try single Register this way & then move on to array - add code below to functions.php:

[WP Codex register_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)

```
<?php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu' );
}
?>
```

Display menu on page - add to header.php:

[WP Codex wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
    'menu'            => 'Primary Menu',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

Tip - both of your entries have a 'menu' class:

Your code:

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main','menu_class' => 'menu' )); ?>
```

Change to:

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main' )); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you bro.

 `<?php wp_nav_menu('fallback_cb=true&theme_location=central&menu_class=menu_center&container=nav&container_class=menu'); ?>`

Worked in my case.